# Searching workflow/process tool based on ZF

Tags: zend-framework, process, workflow

Does anyone know a workflow system based on Zend (or php), which is open source and can be integrated in a project? What do I understand as workflow system:

- User starts a workflow through submitting some start parameter (e.g. SOAP/HTML request)
- Zend runs the workflow in the background (on high server load the operations are lined up in a queue)
- Workflow may be build out of several modules/actions e.g. export xml > create pdf > send pdf to user > send email (Backend)
- User sees current status of the running workflow online and gets the result as soon as finished through ajax requests to the server. (User Interface)
- Admin has a overview of general running workflows (Admin Interface)

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the *workflow* is just a pre-defined set of actions.

I don't believe there is a ready tool for this, but I think you may be interested in running a set of cron jobs from the Zend Framework CLI (e.g. building your own [Zend_Tool Provider](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.writing-providers.html)) and in [`Zend_Queue`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.html).

Comment: Yes I understand a predefined set of actions. But I want to make the actions reusable for different projects.

Comment: Seams like I have to build something my-self :(

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the right tool for such task - eg. Gearman. It is a piece of software solely for the requirements you described. See more here:

- http://www.slideshare.net/felixdv/high-gear-php-with-gearman
- http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/240-Writing-Gearman-Workers-in-PHP.html

Comment: Sounds pretty amazing! but I don't have a lot of tasks running simultaneously, however I have multiple workflows with similar actions. So I want to create actions. Line up different actions to a workflow and have a progress shown over the actions. Gearman is not the right tool for me, thou. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try eZ Components Workflow library: http://www.ezcomponents.org/docs/api/trunk/introduction_Workflow.html

This post describes how to integrate the eZ Components library with Zend:
http://devzone.zend.com/article/156

Other than that I haven't found any real examples of integrating the eZ workflow classes with a Zend MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has a component for this. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/workflow.html

Oro platform has a bundle for this.
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/WorkflowBundle/Resources/doc/index.md

Otherwise, you could build your own implementation based on maybe the State design pattern. Here is a nice example from Sebastian Bergman. 
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/state